# Retrieve text of nested div inside a div

Tags: jquery

I have an html

```
<div onclick="get_nested_value">
       <div class="inner_div">
               Hello
       </div>
<div>
```

Now i want a jquery function like this

```
function get_nested_value()
{
   alert($(this.'.inner_div').text());
}
```

where `this.'.inner_div'` must point to class `inner_div`

But i must have been doing some silly syntactical error.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-
    in html:-

```
  <div onclick="get_nested_value(this)">
        <div class="inner_div">
           Hello
      </div>
   <div>


function get_nested_value(e)
{
   alert($(e).find('.inner_div').text());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified html should be like following. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/t3gp4L5s/1/)

```
<div onclick="get_nested_value();">
    <div class="inner_div">Hello</div>
<div>

function get_nested_value() {
    console.log($(".inner_div").text().trim());
    alert($(".inner_div").text().trim());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `onclick=()` makes me sad.

```
<div class="nested_getter">
    <div class="inner_div">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>

$('.nested_getter').click(function(){
    console.log($('.inner_div', this).text());
});
```

[the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1u9hqd2b/)

Answer (score 0):

pass `this` in html

### html

```
 <div onclick="get_nested_value(this)">
       <div class="inner_div">
               Hello
       </div>
<div>


 function get_nested_value(elm) {

    alert($(".inner_div", elm).text());
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sqL17sj1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.outerDiv').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var innerDivText = $(this).find('.inner_div').text();
    alert(innerDivText);
});

<div class="outerDiv">
   <div class="inner_div">
   This is my inner div 1
   </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/erwinli/3ybfsrrh/)

Answer (score -1):

Try it. This working code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function get_nested_value(obj){
                    alert($(obj).find(".inner_div").text());
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div onclick="get_nested_value(this)">
            <div class="inner_div">
                Hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```